# Spinner in Fragment Populates With Values From MySQL Database After Second Load

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have added a spinner to my fragment activity, which is supposed to get values from the mysql database server. When running the code, I notice the values only appear on my spinner, the second time the fragment is requested by the user (from a menu).

I used the fragment's onCreateView method to populate the spinner with values (through an ArrayAdapter). Here is the code for the onCreateView method:

```
public class AddShopFragement extends Fragment {

private ArrayAdapter shopsAdapter;
private List<RegisteredShop> registeredShopList = new ArrayList<RegisteredShop>();

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_shop_fragement, container, false);
    AddShopOnClickListener listener = new AddShopOnClickListener(getActivity());
    Button addShop = (Button) fragView.findViewById(R.id.AddStoreButton);
    addShop.setOnClickListener(listener);
    GetRegisteredShopsBackgroundTask bl = new GetRegisteredShopsBackgroundTask(getActivity());
    bl.execute();
    registeredShopList = ((UserSession) getActivity().getApplication()).getRegisteredShopList();
    if (registeredShopList.size() != 0) {
        Spinner registeredStores = (Spinner) fragView.findViewById(R.id.generalShopSpinner);
        shopsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(fragView.getContext(), android.R.layout
                .simple_spinner_dropdown_item, registeredShopList);
        registeredStores.setAdapter(shopsAdapter);
    } 

    return fragView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that your background task which pulls the data is not finished by the time you try using it.

```
GetRegisteredShopsBackgroundTask bl = new GetRegisteredShopsBackgroundTask(getActivity());
bl.execute();
registeredShopList = ((UserSession) getActivity().getApplication()).getRegisteredShopList();
```

Quick way:
Only create the adapter once the task is finished. This will work for you, but it is wrong and you shouldn't be doing it.

Correct way:
You want you make an adapter regardless of `registeredShopList` being empty. Then all `GetRegisteredShopsBackgroundTask` needs to do is call `shopsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` when it is finished. Remember to do this on the UI thread.

The issue here is that you will need to implement a custom adapter (implement BaseAdapter), since `ArrayAdapter`'s dataset will not update when `notifyDataSetChanged` is called. Your custom adapter can reference a global list, or a local list that you set before the `notifyDataSetChanged` call.